# Using Modman to install a starter theme

Tags: module, theme, modman

I am using modman to manage modules for a Magento project.

I want to know whether its viable to use modman to manage my theme files also.

Therefore the advantage will be my Magento base installation will be untouched and all my edits will be done through my modman directory. Has anyone tried this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Magento templating has already advanced features onboard to leave the base theme untouched(really recommend using this)

also since 1.9 you can add a file in your theme `package/theme/etc/theme.xml` where you can set the parent theme.

You could add your custom theme package to modman if you like.

I do the same for bought themes.

- Install bought theme `app/design/frontend/bought/theme`
- Install custom theme `app/design/frontend/my/default`
- Add `etc/theme.xml` with a parent

  `<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <theme>
      <parent>bought/theme</parent>
  </theme>`

This way of overriding allows me to use custom templates for products, categories and others.

Answer (score 2):

You can of course also use modman to manage your theme files. The procedure is exactly the same. Put the theme in a folder, put an appropriate modman file in it and do a `./modman deploy-all` or a `./modman/deploy Your_Theme` if you put your theme in the folder `Your_Theme`.

But make sure that you set "Allow Symlinks" to "Yes" under System - Configuration - Developer - Template Settings. Otherwise, you will get a blank page or you will see the `base/default` theme since Magento does not accept your symlinked template files.

Comment: Unfortunately it looks like Modman symlinking works with Magento 2's template files only if original files reside anywhere in the $MAGE_ROOT directory - http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/95071/magento-2-does-not-allow-linking-modules-using-symlinks#comment127505_95077