# Magento2 CSS was blocked due to MIME type mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff)

Tags: magento2, css

I am using Magento 2 in Windows 10 using xampp.

I have installed magento2 and it was running perfectly. After that, I migrate data from magento1 with migration tool.

Now I am having an error with the resource from “
(CSS path)” was blocked due to MIME type mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).

Already tried to deploy static content many times with cache and index refresh. URL rewrite is already ON.

Can anyone please help me out?

Thanks

Comment: did you check whether the files in the error is exist in the given path ?

Comment: Yes, All files are exist. but when I check in firebug, its give me error like 404 file not found and for same file its give me another error like Mime Type mismatch.

Answer (score 8):

Download the .htaccess file for your specific magento version and put it inside the pub/static folder in the default magento directory and these errors should vanish.

I also faced a very similar issue. After a lot of deliberation I was able to understand that this problem mainly occurred because I deleted the .htaccess file inside the pub/static folder.

Comment: I still have the same .htaccess file inside pub/static/ but still i get the error. I also downloaded the file specific to my magento version and compared it to the old file and they are exactly same.

Comment: and where can we find these .htaccess files?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same error and it turned out that the mismatch error was wrong. I came across this: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10325 which explained that the mismatch error is a red herring and in fact the real error is a 404 fie not found. You should be able to work out if this applies to you by opening the page in chrome, going to the console and clicking on a file name that's erroring. For me it gave a file not found. Obviously you then need to work out why the file isn't there.

Comment: For me en_US/jquery.js was missing after minimising JS. I'm not sure what was referring to the non minimised version but manually adding it fixed it for me.

Comment: Give this person a medal, saviour

Answer (score 1):

The issue may related to the fact that there's no Symlinks on Windows. There's 2 ways of fixing that:

### 1. Changing setting in file

In `app/etc/di.xml` change

```
Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Symlink
```

to:

```
Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Copy
```

### 2. Changing settings in Configuration

(From https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/95077/44597)

Go to `Stores => Configuration => Advanced => Developer => Template Settings` and change `Allow Symlinks => No`

Answer (score 0):

I moved away from using m2 on wamp / xampp within windows for exactly this reason. Have you considered docker? https://github.com/meanbee/docker-magento2

Answer (score 0):

in my case it was all folder permession , the easy fix is to just do the following:

1- change the /pub folder permission to 777:

```
sudo chmod 777 pub -Rf
```

2- redeploy the site static contents:

```
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

in case u have multi-lang site, write like this:

```
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f en_US ar_SA
```