# Magento 2 why CSS was blocked due to MIME type mismatch

Tags: magento2, css, catalog, products

I have just added custom CSS in the **app/Vendor/theme/Magento_Catalog/web/css/custom.css**

After that, I have run the CLI command `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` and clear the cache.

When I refresh the page I have found the below issue:

> The resource from
>   “http://localhost/mageento2/pub/static/version1488530702/frontend/Vendor/theme/en_US/Magento_Catalog/css/custom.css”
>   was blocked due to MIME type mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options:
>   nosniff).

After that I have researched this issue and found the answer in below link:

[Magento2 CSS was blocked due to MIME type mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff)](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/152625/magento2-css-was-blocked-due-to-mime-type-mismatch-x-content-type-options-nosn)

I have changed settings already **app/etc/di.xml** after install the magento. Also, Changed the settings in Configuration `Stores => Configuration => Advanced => Developer => Template Settings and change Allow Symlinks => No`.

Also, when I go to the `app\pub\static\frontend\Vendor\deom\en_US\Magento_Catalog`, I couldn't found my custom.css file.

I have included this CSS in the **app\design\frontend\Vendor\theme\Magento_Catalog\layout\catalog_product_view.xml**

Please see the below is code of .XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
    <css src="Magento_Catalog::css/magnific-popup.css" />
  </head>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template"
               name="custom.js" as="custom.js" template="Magento_Catalog::product/js.phtml"/>
    </referenceContainer>
        <move element="page.main.title" destination="product.info.main" before="-"/>
        <move element="product.info.stock.sku" destination="product.info.price" after="product.price.final"/>
        <move element="product.info.review" destination="product.info.main" before="product.info.price"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

I have put the CSS file in this directory **app\pub\static\frontend\Vendor\theme\en_US\Magento_Catalog\css\custom.css**

Can anyone describe why this issue is occurring? So, we can aware of this issue in future.

I have installed **Magento ver. 2.1.3**. Please help..

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/108685/how-to-add-a-custom-css-file-in-magento-2

Comment: @Ankit Shah I want to load `custom.css` file in only product detail page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override the below file in your theme

**magento\vendor\magento\module-catalog\view\frontend\layout\catalog_product_view.xml**

Add your css under `gallery.css`

```
<head>
    <css src="mage/gallery/gallery.css"/>
    <css src="<path>/custom.css"/>
</head>
```

Comment: I am trying to add the [link]http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/ pop gallery on the product detail page. I have disabled the fotorama fullscreen from `view.xml`. The pop is appear but it's showing other images like my product has only 4 image and it's showing 35 appr.