# Magento 2 CSS and Javascipt Not Loading

Tags: magento-2.1, js-css

I am running magento 2.1.5 and every thing was working fine. Suddenly my CSS and Js files are not loading I am getting error

```
 http://mymagentourl.com/pub/static/version1491202457/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/css/styles-m.css” was blocked due to MIME type mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).
```

what is the meaning of **was blocked due to MIME type mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).**

I am running magento in nginx Web Server and my mode is production. I tried

- remove Var/* folder
- re deploy static content
- remove cache
- flush
  cache

I am not able to understand why my css and js is not loading?

Comment: It looks like the same problem: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/152625/magento2-css-was-blocked-due-to-mime-type-mismatch-x-content-type-options-nosn

Comment: Possible but there is no accepted solution moreover I tried those too. @Nikola

Comment: there is something wrong in nginx rewrite.

Comment: it was working well before and there has been no changes after then.

Answer (score 1):

Navigate to your database and perform following steps:-

- Find core_config_data table and open it.
- Add a new row and provide "dev/static/sign" under path and "0" under value (without quotes) and leave other fields unchanged and save it.
- flush cache `php bin/magento cache:flush`
- perform static content deploy `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

Comment: Ya had that solution in mind and done that but this removes the dynamic generation of static file url of version which is removed. So is this ok?

Comment: Please let me know about your server environment (linux or windows) and if the problem is browser depended or not.

Comment: Linux with nginx web server no its not browser dependent.