# Magento 2.3 it's not working properly in localhost

Tags: magento2, admin, home, magento2.3

I have installed new Magento 2.3 in my localhost. it is a successfully installed. But When I open an admin URL it comes with blank URL. Also, my homepage comes without Magento default logo. 
Also, I face another issue on homepage When I clicked on to create an account it redirects successfully but it comes with a blank page.

Please see attached images for better ideas.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Here is system.log

```
2018-11-30 08:35:09] main.CRITICAL: Invalid template file: 'D:/xampp/htdocs/Akashdev/Magento23/vendor/magento/module-backend/view/adminhtml/templates/page/js/require_js.phtml' in module: 'Magento_Backend' block's name: 'require.js' [] []
[2018-11-30 08:35:09] main.CRITICAL: Invalid template file: 'D:/xampp/htdocs/Akashdev/Magento23/vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/templates/wysiwyg/active_editor.phtml' in module: 'Magento_Ui' block's name: 'theme.active.editor' [] []
[2018-11-30 08:35:09] main.CRITICAL: Invalid template file: 'D:/xampp/htdocs/Akashdev/Magento23/vendor/magento/module-translation/view/base/templates/translate.phtml' in module: 'Magento_Translation' block's name: 'translate' [] []
[2018-11-30 08:35:09] main.CRITICAL: Invalid template file: 'D:/xampp/htdocs/Akashdev/Magento23/vendor/magento/module-backend/view/adminhtml/templates/page/js/components.phtml' in module: '' block's name: 'head.components' [] []
[2018-11-30 08:35:09] main.CRITICAL: Invalid template file: 'D:/xampp/htdocs/Akashdev/Magento23/vendor/magento/module-backend/view/adminhtml/templates/page/js/calendar.phtml' in module: '' block's name: 'head.calendar' [] []
[2018-11-30 08:35:09] main.CRITICAL: Invalid template file: 'D:/xampp/htdocs/Akashdev/Magento23/vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/templates/logger.phtml' in module: 'Magento_Ui' block's name: 'logger' [] []
[2018-11-30 08:35:09] main.CRITICAL: Invalid template file: 'D:/xampp/htdocs/Akashdev/Magento23/vendor/magento/module-backend/view/adminhtml/templates/page/header.phtml' in module: 'Magento_Backend' block's name: 'logo' [] []
[2018-11-30 08:35:09] main.CRITICAL: Invalid template file: 'D:/xampp/htdocs/Akashdev/Magento23/vendor/magento/module-backend/view/adminhtml/templates/admin/login.phtml' in module: 'Magento_Backend' block's name: 'admin.login' [] []
[2018-11-30 08:35:09] main.CRITICAL: Invalid template file: 'D:/xampp/htdocs/Akashdev/Magento23/vendor/magento/module-backend/view/adminhtml/templates/page/copyright.phtml' in module: 'Magento_Backend' block's name: 'copyright' [] []
[2018-11-30 08:35:15] main.CRITICAL: Invalid template file: 'D:/xampp/htdocs/Akashdev/Magento23/vendor/magento/module-backend/view/adminhtml/templates/page/js/require_js.phtml' in module: 'Magento_Backend' block's name: 'require.js' [] []
[2018-11-30 08:35:15] main.CRITICAL: Invalid template file: 'D:/xampp/htdocs/Akashdev/Magento23/vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/templates/wysiwyg/active_editor.phtml' in module: 'Magento_Ui' block's name: 'theme.active.editor' [] []
[2018-11-30 08:35:15] main.CRITICAL: Invalid template file: 'D:/xampp/htdocs/Akashdev/Magento23/vendor/magento/module-translation/view/base/templates/translate.phtml' in module: 'Magento_Translation' block's name: 'translate' [] []
[2018-11-30 08:35:15] main.CRITICAL: Invalid template file: 'D:/xampp/htdocs/Akashdev/Magento23/vendor/magento/module-backend/view/adminhtml/templates/page/js/components.phtml' in module: '' block's name: 'head.components' [] []
[2018-11-30 08:35:15] main.CRITICAL: Invalid template file: 'D:/xampp/htdocs/Akashdev/Magento23/vendor/magento/module-backend/view/adminhtml/templates/page/js/calendar.phtml' in module: '' block's name: 'head.calendar' [] []
[2018-11-30 08:35:15] main.CRITICAL: Invalid template file: 'D:/xampp/htdocs/Akashdev/Magento23/vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/templates/logger.phtml' in module: 'Magento_Ui' block's name: 'logger' [] []
[2018-11-30 08:35:15] main.CRITICAL: Invalid template file: 'D:/xampp/htdocs/Akashdev/Magento23/vendor/magento/module-backend/view/adminhtml/templates/page/header.phtml' in module: 'Magento_Backend' block's name: 'logo' [] []
[2018-11-30 08:35:15] main.CRITICAL: Invalid template file: 'D:/xampp/htdocs/Akashdev/Magento23/vendor/magento/module-backend/view/adminhtml/templates/admin/login.phtml' in module: 'Magento_Backend' block's name: 'admin.login' [] []
[2018-11-30 08:35:15] main.CRITICAL: Invalid template file: 'D:/xampp/htdocs/Akashdev/Magento23/vendor/magento/module-backend/view/adminhtml/templates/page/copyright.phtml' in module: 'Magento_Backend' block's name: 'copyright' [] []
```

Comment: Is there anything in the logs?

Comment: enable error reporting and check

Comment: I have attached log error please check it.

Comment: Which PHP version you are using?

Comment: @SunnyRahevar My PHP version is 7.1.20

Comment: Please run all the command like static content deploy , cache flush and give the proper permission.

Comment: @sv3n Thank you. Your link is very useful for me. Now my site is working.

Comment: @AkashPatel Did you install 2.3 in windows?

Comment: @zus Yes I have installed in windows.

Comment: @AkashPatel Can i get Magento 2.3 Installation Guide?

Comment: @zus Please follow steps as per this link "https://www.magestore.com/magento-2-tutorial/how-to-install-magento-2-on-localhost-via-xampp/"

Comment: @AkashPatel Did  you ever face this error while installation?   Log Error https://justpaste.it/340g6

Comment: @zus No, I did not face this error.

Answer (score 15):

This would be a bug that addresses [this commit](https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/8110949e4dd4faa8d36b25ecfeb7779ebbac5741#diff-643a52d0419707fc6b1a9c95a9b5a632L131). Author changed `$path` to

```
$this->fileDriver->getRealPath($path)
```

which is simply calling `realpath()` on `$path` but that might change directory separators on the `$path` that previously were affected by

```
#/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template/File/Validator.php:114
$filename = str_replace('\\', '/', $filename);
```

On a Windows OS this will revert changes of above `str_replace` so that a path like

```
D:/Magento2.3/vendor/magento
```

will be canonicalized to its Windows specific version:

```
D:\Magento2.3\vendor\magento
```

and this will not result in a successful comparison within `isPathInDirectories()` method of `Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\File\Validator` class:

```
foreach ($directories as $directory) {
    if (0 === strpos($realPath, $directory)) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

## Solution

Currently we can go for a dirty quick change in the above `foreach` loop so that we can run our magento with no further problems on this:

```
#/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template/File/Validator.php:139
foreach ($directories as $directory) {
    // Add this line
    $realDirectory = $this->fileDriver->getRealPath($directory);
    // and replace `$directory` with `$realDirectory`
    if (0 === strpos($realPath, $realDirectory)) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: why not use `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` instead of hardcoded variants of slashes?

Comment: Taking care of `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` should be done by the authors as we aren't aware how many manual replacements exist.

Answer (score 0):

If you installed this on your local computer (not a server on the network).

please try to change baseurl in db core_config_data to: 127.0.0.1

browse your website at either http://127.0.0.1 or http://localhost

Comment: I have tried but it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

This link should fix your issue.
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/19480#issue-386162790