# Fresh Magento 2.3 Resource Files Not Working After Installed in Windows

Tags: jquery, installation, requirejs, sample-data, magento2.3

Fresh Magento 2.3 installed in windows, after resource check and completed everything successfully installed, then if i open my website i am getting error like,

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Check this link: After installing magento 2.3 admin login page cant open properly

```
Find : /vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template/File/Validator.php:139

find : 
foreach ($directories as $directory) {
    if (0 === strpos($realPath, $directory)) {
        return true;
    }
}

Replace with:
foreach ($directories as $directory) {
    $realDirectory = $this->fileDriver->getRealPath($directory);
    // and replace `$directory` with `$realDirectory`
    if (0 === strpos($realPath, $realDirectory)) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

It's working

Comment: Still getting same error, Is there anything else shall i need to do?

Comment: after that apply all command.

Comment: Yes, I replaced by your code still not working.

Comment: check this link , https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/251926/magento-2-3-its-not-working-properly-in-localhost?rq=1