# Magento 2 Upgrade error Backend is not opening

Tags: magento2.3, upgrade, backend

After upgrading Magento to 2.3, My website's frontend is working fine with complete CSS. however, I am unable to open admin-backend when I hit the admin URL. it is only loading but the admin-login page is not opening in the End 500 error is displaying on the browser. 
do anyone know why it is occurring.

Comment: Have you checked your server error log?

Comment: please follow this link https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/251926/magento-2-3-its-not-working-properly-in-localhost

Comment: check error log , it is simple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overide the code in,

`vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template/File/Validator.php`

```
protected function isPathInDirectories($path, $directories)
{
    if (!is_array($directories)) {
        $directories = (array)$directories;
    }
    foreach ($directories as $directory) {
        if (0 === strpos($this->fileDriver->getRealPath($path), $directory)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

You can override vendor\magento\framework\View\Element\Template\File\Validator.php Using preference

Just Create a custom module and add below code to your di.xml file

now create the class [VENDOR][EXTENSION]\View\Element\Template\File\Validator that extends Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\File\Validator

Copy that code and replace the below function,

```
protected function isPathInDirectories($path, $directories)
{
    $realPath = str_replace('\\', '/', $this->fileDriver->getRealPath($path));
    if (!is_array($directories)) {
        $directories = (array)$directories;
    }
    foreach ($directories as $directory) {
        if (0 === strpos($realPath, $directory)) {
            return true;
        }   
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: This is bad practise, you should not be editing core code like this, especially code in the vendor directory!

Comment: but it still doesn't work for me.

Comment: Did you overide the file or Replace that code directly in vendor file?

Comment: yes, I override the code.

Comment: remove overide and add that code directly in vendor and check

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and fixed it by the below solution. You may try it

[Magento 2.3.1 is not working in Xampp](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/269104/magento-2-3-1-is-not-working-in-xampp)

Comment: it doesn't work :-(

Comment: Please try to run the below commands from the Magento root installation

rm -rf var/di/* var/generation/* var/cache/* var/log/* var/page_cache/* var/session/* var/view_preprocessed/* pub/static/*
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento cache:flush

Comment: rm -rf generated/ var/view_preprocessed  var/page_cache , php bin/magento setup:upgrade , condtent deplot and last permission 777 command all the command run but result is same