# Magento hangs when i click install, using wamp server

Tags: magento2, installation, permissions

I'm trying to install Magento version 2.3.2 on a wamp server, Apache version is 2.4.39 PHP 7.1.29 MySQL 5.7.26 when i reach the install button after filling all my details it freezes on 0% and the console 
log reads:

Starting Magento installation:

File permissions check...

Required extensions check...

Enabling Maintenance Mode...

Installing deployment configuration...

Installing database schema: Schema creation/updates:

Any help greatly appreciated

Comment: Have you checked in system.log or exception.log? Any error shows there?

Comment: Ive got this in event viewer,

Comment: Magento[4348]
main.CRITICAL: The specified "C:/wamp/www/magento/generated/code/Magento/Swatches/Block/Adminhtml/Product/Attribute/Edit/FormFactory.php.4348" file couldn't be written. Warning!file_put_contents(C:/wamp/www/magento/generated/code/Magento/Swatches/Block/Adminhtml/Product/Attribute/Edit/FormFactory.php.4348): failed to open stream: Resource temporarily unavailable Class Magento\Swatches\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Attribute\Edit\FormFactory generation error: The requested class did not generate properly, because the 'generated' directory permission is read-only.

Comment: If --- after running the 'bin/magento setup:di:compile' CLI command when the 'generated' directory permission is set to write --- the requested class did not generate properly, then you must add the generated class object to the signature of the related construct method, only.

Comment: Havent got an exception log?

Comment: I changed the permissions on C:/wamp/www/magento/generated/code/Magento/Swatches/Block/Adminhtml/Product/Attribute/Edit/FormFactory.php and install appears to have completed, however have a white screen when i log in?

Comment: Have you given required permission to all directories and files? Please check following answer:- https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/91870/magento-2-folder-file-permissions

Comment: Hi Raj, I gave full permissions to the magento folder and subfolders, this is on a localserver (wamp), this gave the following error Fatal error: Namespace declaration statement has to be the very first statement or after any declare call in the script in C:\wamp\www\magento\vendor\magento\framework\View\Element\Template\File\Validator.php on line 6 so i removed the white space and now the error shows on line 2, but no white space?

Comment: Try following solution:- https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/251792/invalid-template-file-upgrade-issue-from-2-2-6-to-2-2-7-or-2-3

Comment: Thanks Raj, i replaced the code for protected function and the code on line114 (109 on mine), not sure where to find the registratio.php file (tried a search it brings up quite a few) the the error now is Fatal error: Namespace declaration statement has to be the very first statement or after any declare call in the script in C:\wamp\www\magento\vendor\magento\framework\View\Element\Template\File\Validator.php on line 1

Comment: Hi Raj, Changed the Validator.php file from UTF-8 to ANSI and it seems to be working, thanks

Comment: That's Great Mark. :)